# how to clear out a cookie in php

Tags: php, cookies

There I have a cookie which holds the letter a I have also got a button called clear when the user clickes the clear button I want the letter a not to be inside the cookie but I still want to keep the cookie the cookie just needs to be empty

heres my code

clear button

```
<form action="" method="POST">
 <button type="submit" name="clear" id="clear">clear</button> 
</form>
```

and my cookie code

```
setcookie('a', 'a', time()+1045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852104545432357027027183560378521045454323570270271835603785210454543235702702718356037852);
```

Comment: `time()+ ...` what the?

Comment: could you please give me your version of my code thank you

Answer (score 0):

*'... but I still want to keep the cookie. The cookie just needs to be empty'* - I take this to mean modifying the cookie.

```
$a = ''; 

setcookie($a, $a, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // will clear the 'a' cookie.
```

Forgive me if this is not what you want.

time()[ the current time ] + 86400( 1 day ) * 30 means that the formally 'a' cookie will expire in 30 days.